# Create a calculated column to be yes IF([due date]=[Today]-31, "yes", no) or custom view

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

Im trying to set up a calculated column to look at another calculated date column and if its under a month (ie its due to be renewed) than say yes.

if i cant do that can i create a custom view from a calculated date column?

the greater than or equal to [Today]-31 doesnt work on calculated columns?

My end goal is to use flow to look for the yes column and then create a new list item, but i cant use odata filters from calculated columns and [Today]-31 doesnt work on calculated columns? Kinda stuck

Answer (score 0):

To get today's date in calculate column, you should use the function `TODAY()` instead of [Today]. Change your formula to this

```
=IF([due date]=TODAY()-31,"yes","no")
```